# UITableView renders correctly in Simulator iOS 7.0, but not for iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an iPad app (XCode 5, iOS 7, ARC, Storyboards).  When running the app in the Debugger, Simulator iOS 7.0, it works fine.  When running in the Simulator iOS 6.1, I get black cells in the UITableView.  Here is what I'm talking about:

[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Unfortunately, my iPad that I do testing on has iOS 7.0, so there is no way I can test it on 6.1.  Any ideas how to determine if this will carryover to a live iPad running 6.1?  or should I now set the target iOS to 7.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS simulator is usually reasonably accurate, so I'll assume that the same results will appear on an iPad running iOS 6.1. You might want to check how the cells appear on an iOS 6.1 storyboard, to make sure that you aren't setting them to black yourself by accident. If you go to your storyboard's file navigator view, there's an option to view it as iOS 7 or iOS 6.1 and earlier (outlined in red). [image: Storyboard screen-capture]

If this isn't the issue, I'd check any code you have that might be affecting the appearance of the cell. I know that the tintColor property, for example, has had its behaviour changed.

Comment: I checked everything you suggested; where can I find the changes made to the tintColor property in iOS 7?

Comment: Found it!  The background color was clear... thank you for your help... I truly appreciate it... SD